# InvalidOperationException when modifiying NavigationStack in a ContentPage Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, content-pages

There is a weird problem where I cannot manage to do any modification on the NavigationStack when I am in a ContentPage.

What I want to do is to add a new page and remove the previous inside a Page whenever the device orientation has changed.

Below Code should handle the problem of changing a page:

```
private async void DoTest()
{
    Page originalRootPage = App.CurrentInitialized.Navigation.NavigationStack.Last();
    await App.CurrentInitialized.Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage_Landscape());
    App.CurrentInitialized.Navigation.RemovePage(originalRootPage);
}
```

I call the above code in this overridden method:

```
protected override async void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
    DeviceInfo.SetSize(width, height);
    if (!DeviceInfo.IsOrientationPortrait())
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send<HomePage>(this, "Hi");
    }

}
```

I used an own defined class DeviceInfo. However, IsOrientationPortrait checks if the height of the device is larger than the devices width.

Calling the DoTest method whenever you are triggering a command works! But not during orientation changes.

If there is a better way to do change the Page UI design during landscape. Please help!

Comment: Removing a page when an orientation changes seems like a situation asking for trouble :) Can you explain why you need to do that, there maybe a better approach.

Comment: what is the message in your InvalidOperationException?